# R Matrix Package: Meaning of the attributes in the dgCMatrix class for sparse matrices

Tags: r, pointers, matrix, sparse-matrix

I've looked at the [Matrix](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Matrix/index.html) package and at their [slides](http://matrix.r-forge.r-project.org/slides/2009-07-10-Rennes/MM-talk.pdf). I was trying to understand what is the intution and the meaning behind the arguments in the `dgCMatrix` class. I understand that

- `@i` gives the zero-based row indeces of the non-zero entries in the matrix.
- `@j` gives the zero-based column indeces of the non-zero entries in the matrix.
- `@x` gives the non-zero elements at the `(i,j)` positions.

However I don't understand the meaning of the pointer `@p`. The [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Matrix/versions/1.2-18/topics/sparseMatrix) says

> numeric (integer-valued) vector of pointers, one for each column (or row), to the initial (zero-based) index of elements in the column (or row).

This is not very informative. In the "detail" section, on the same page they explain more

> If `i` or `j` is missing then `p` must be a non-decreasing integer vector whose first element is zero. It provides the compressed, or “pointer” representation of the row or column indices, whichever is missing. The expanded form of `p`, `rep(seq_along(dp),dp)` where `dp <- diff(p)`, is used as the (1-based) row or column indices.

Which to me is definitely non-intuitive. Can someone provide a simple explanation of what `p` represents? I've created a Minimal Working Example but feel free to create a new one.

---

## Minimal Working Example

```
# Define non-zero values and their row/col indeces
i_indeces <- c(1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9)
j_indeces <- c(2, 9, 6, 3, 9, 10)
values <- c(60, 20, 10, 40, 30, 50)
# Create the sparse matrix
A <- sparseMatrix(
    i=i_indeces,
    j=j_indeces,
    x=values,
    dims=c(10, 20)
)
```

Where

```
> str(A)
Formal class 'dgCMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 6 slots
  ..@ i       : int [1:6] 0 5 3 2 7 8
  ..@ p       : int [1:21] 0 0 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 5 ...
  ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 10 20
  ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : NULL
  ..@ x       : num [1:6] 60 40 10 20 30 50
  ..@ factors : list()
```

and

```
> A
10 x 20 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"

 [1,] . 60  . . .  . . .  .  . . . . . . . . . . .
 [2,] .  .  . . .  . . .  .  . . . . . . . . . . .
 [3,] .  .  . . .  . . . 20  . . . . . . . . . . .
 [4,] .  .  . . . 10 . .  .  . . . . . . . . . . .
 [5,] .  .  . . .  . . .  .  . . . . . . . . . . .
 [6,] .  . 40 . .  . . .  .  . . . . . . . . . . .
 [7,] .  .  . . .  . . .  .  . . . . . . . . . . .
 [8,] .  .  . . .  . . . 30  . . . . . . . . . . .
 [9,] .  .  . . .  . . .  . 50 . . . . . . . . . .
[10,] .  .  . . .  . . .  .  . . . . . . . . . . .
```

## Note

I understand that `rep(seq_along(diff(A@p)), diff(A@p))` is a rearranged form of `j_indeces` but I still don't understand what it means.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally understood! I'm posting the answer for future reference.
Looking at the matrix `A`

```
 [1,] . 60  . . .  . . .  .  . . . . . . . . . . .
 [2,] .  .  . . .  . . .  .  . . . . . . . . . . .
 [3,] .  .  . . .  . . . 20  . . . . . . . . . . .
 [4,] .  .  . . . 10 . .  .  . . . . . . . . . . .
 [5,] .  .  . . .  . . .  .  . . . . . . . . . . .
 [6,] .  . 40 . .  . . .  .  . . . . . . . . . . .
 [7,] .  .  . . .  . . .  .  . . . . . . . . . . .
 [8,] .  .  . . .  . . . 30  . . . . . . . . . . .
 [9,] .  .  . . .  . . .  . 50 . . . . . . . . . .
[10,] .  .  . . .  . . .  .  . . . . . . . . . . .
```

the attribute `p`

```
> A@p
 [1] 0 0 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 5 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6
```

basically counts the number of non-zero element in each row. It is constructed like this

- The first element is always `0` by convention (not sure why), so `p = [0]`
- Next, start at the top left of our matrix  (i.e. at `[1, 1]`) and we look at each column from the left-most column to the right-most column and we add to our "counter" (which is now set to `0`) the number of non-zero elements in that column.

  - Column `1` has no non-zero elements so we add `0` to our counter. `p=[0,0]`.
  - Column `2` has one non-zero element (`60`) so we add `1` to our counter `p=[0, 0, 0+1]=[0,0,1]`
  - Column `3` has one non-zero element (`40`) so `p=[0, 0, 1, 1+1]=[0, 0, 1, 2]`
  - Column `4` has no non-zero elements so  `p=[0, 0, 1, 2, 2+0]=[0, 0, 1, 2, 2]`
  - Column `5` has no non-zero elements so `p=[0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2]`
  - Column `6` has one non-zero element (`10`) so `p=[0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3]`
  - Column `7` has no non-zero elements so `p=[0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3]`
  - Column `8` has no non-zero elements so `p=[0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]`
  - Column `9` has two non zero elements (`20` and `30`) so `p=[0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5]`
  - Column `10` has 1 non-zero element (`50`) so `p=[0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 6]`
  - Columns `11` to `20` have all zero elements so we append `[6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6]`

Therefore we've obtained our desired `p`. The intuition behind is that it's a counter of how many non-zero element there are column-wise going from left to right.